# Argument of #selector cannot refer to a property

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

The goal is to update the below condition to Swift 2.2 syntax, which advises using `#selector or explicitly constructing a Selector`.

```
if activityViewController.respondsToSelector("popoverPresentationController") {

}
```

However, using the below as a replacement fails and generates an error saying `Argument of #selector cannot refer to a property`

```
if activityViewController.respondsToSelector(#selector(popoverPresentationController)) {

}
```

What's the right way to implement this check with `#selector`?

Comment: popOverPresentationController is a property not a func. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
if activityViewController.respondsToSelector(Selector("popoverPresentationController")) {

}
```

Or if you target iOS only

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
    // You can use the property like this
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sourceView
} else {

}
```

Or if your code is not limited to iOS

```
#if os(iOS)
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sourceView
    } else {

    }
#endif
```